# LocationListener in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, location

Can I use LocationListener with LocationManager in fragment? Actually when I use it, it gives me error in this line:

`lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0, (android.location.LocationListener) this);`

and when I do not casts the 4th parameter to `android.location.LocationListener` it gives me error...

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Speedometer extends Fragment implements LocationListener {

    TextView txt;
    public Speedometer(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.speedometer, container, false);

        txt=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.speedometer);

        LocationManager lm= (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0, (android.location.LocationListener) this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if(location==null){
           txt.setText("-.- m/s");
        } else {
            float nCurrentSpeed=location.getSpeed();
            txt.setText(nCurrentSpeed+"m/s");
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: use without cast `lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,this);`

Comment: without cast it gives me error

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you have mistakenly implemented [`com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html) interface that has just one 1 abstract method `onLocationChanged`

You should rather implement [`android.location.LocationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) that has 4 abstract methods

`onLocationChanged(Location location)`,

`onProviderDisabled(String provider)`,

`onProviderEnabled(String provider)`,

`onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)`

Comment: Thank you so much, i used it and my error is removed

Comment: Cool! It is kind of confusing to figure out when to use one or the other...