# How Can I Track a person using its location in Android

Tags: android, mysql, google-maps, geolocation

I am working on a project...I need to track a person using its Geo-location(latitude,longitude)..
**Scenario:** 
 - Person A's Location is updating on server in MYSQL DB when location  become change.
 - Person B need to see person A on Google-map through his/her own device (Android phone)

**Problem**

> When I establish connection to server and try to get location from MYSQL DB ... connection become struck and App crashes.
>   **Note**
>   Person B need to track until it reaches at a specific point.
>   Is there any other way to do this >??
>   **Thanks for Helping in Advance**

**Downloading Tracking Location From Server**

```
private class downloadTrackingLocationsAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String ID = params[1];
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        try {
            // create connection
            URL wsURL=new URL(params[0]);
            conn=(HttpURLConnection) wsURL.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("id", ID);
            String data = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
            byte[] outputInBytes = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(outputInBytes.length));
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(outputInBytes);
            os.close();

            //get data
            InputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            // converting InputStream into String
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(bufferedInputStream);
            String strJSON = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
            scanner.close();
            bufferedInputStream.close();
            return strJSON;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // URL is invalid
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // data retrieval or connection timed out
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // could not read response body
            // (could not create input stream)
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {conn.disconnect(); }
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result !=null) {
            try {
                JSONObject rootObject = new JSONObject(result);

                    double latitude = rootObject.optDouble("lattitude");
                    double longitude = rootObject.optDouble("longitude");

                    LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    PersonB_FragmentMap.updateTrackingLocation(currentLocation);
                Log.i("Location", currentLocation.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Tracking Location Downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Result Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**I am Calling this Class using a function continuously**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use AlarmManager and services and do it in background.
For more details of AlarmManager [refer this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

**Update data from server at regular time intervals in background process using AlarmManager, BroadcastReceiver, Service and Notification Manager.**

First Activate AlarmManager. Write below code in Activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

     private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 30;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            setRecurringAlarm(this);
        }

        private void setRecurringAlarm(Context context) {

            Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
            updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
            Intent downloader = new Intent(context, MyStartServiceReceiver.class);
            downloader.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, downloader,       PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntent);

            Log.d("MyActivity", "Set alarmManager.setRepeating to: " + updateTime.getTime().toLocaleString());

      }

}


First create BroadcastReceiver Class
public class MyStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent dailyUpdater = new Intent(context, MyService.class); 
            context.startService(dailyUpdater);
            Log.d("AlarmReceiver", "Called context.startService from AlarmReceiver.onReceive");
    } 
}
```

When application is closed or is in background, periodically fetch data from server and show notification on status bar.

Create Service

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    public MyService() {
       super("MyServiceName");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("MyService", "About to execute MyTask");
        new MyTask().execute();
        this.sendNotification(this);
    }
    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override 
         protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
                Log.d("MyService - MyTask", "Calling doInBackground within MyTask");
               return false;
        } 
 }        
private void sendNotification(Context context) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        NotificationManager notificationMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification =  new Notification(android.R.drawable.star_on, "Refresh", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Title","Content", contentIntent);
        notificationMgr.notify(0, notification);
     }
}
```

Don't forget write below lines in AndroidManifest.xml File

```
<service android:name="MyService" ></service> 
<receiver android:name="MyStartServiceReceiver" ></receiver>
```

Comment: You Helped me alot ..thank u very much ... it means i need to paste my code which is in doInBackground() function to the doInBackground() function in MyTask Class... im i ryt  ?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233219/locationlistener-in-fragment

Comment: try to create new question as to how to manage Alarm Manager with the problem you are facing